# How can I point a precise location in a book? it seems there is not much people use the expression like "the third last paragraph"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

assume there are some people discussing a book.

one would say page number n, paragraph m.

another one would say page number n, the third last paragraph.

is it a idiomatic expression? or there is a more idiomatic expression?

to get more guarantee, I've googled following 3 expressions

"the third last paragraph" gets About 14,900 results.

"the last third paragraph" gets About 3,730 results.

"the 3rd last paragraph" gets About 2,120 results.

I cannot imagine more possible expressions that may be more clear and idiomatic.

any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“the third last paragraph” is correct.

The same way as **the nth most**, and "the 2nd most" will get you a lot of results.